# Decrypted string not equivalent to another string with the same value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on Login project in flutter encryption and decryption works just like how I expected to be, this is how I decrypted the user password:

```
      final key = encrypterQERT.Key.fromUtf8('key');
      final iv = encrypterQERT.IV.fromUtf8('key');

      final encrypter = encrypterQERT.Encrypter(encrypterQERT.AES(key, mode: encrypterQERT.AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
      final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(_passValues.elementAt(0), iv: iv);
```

How it was encrypted:

```
    final _getKey = encrypter.Key.fromUtf8(key);
    final encryptServ = encrypter.Encrypter(encrypter.AES(_getKey, mode: encrypter.AESMode.cbc));
    final InitVect = encrypter.IV.fromUtf8(key.substring(0,16));

    encrypter.Encrypted _encryptDat = encryptServ.encrypt(Value,iv: InitVect);
   return _encryptDat;
```

Now I tried to determine if the user input is equivalent to the decrypted password:

```
     List<dynamic> _passValues = <dynamic>[];
      for(final _userPass in _getPass.rows) {
        dynamic _getFirst = _userPass.assoc().values.elementAt(0);
        print(_getFirst);
        _passValues.add(_getFirst);
      }

      final key = encrypterQERT.Key.fromUtf8('key');
      final iv = encrypterQERT.IV.fromUtf8('key');

      final encrypter = encrypterQERT.Encrypter(encrypterQERT.AES(key, mode: encrypterQERT.AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
      final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(_passValues.elementAt(0), iv: iv);
      print(_userPasswordInput);
      print(decrypted);

      if(decrypted == _userPasswordinput) {
        print("Passed");
      } else {
        print("Failed");
      }
```

And the output were:

`mypass mypass Failed`

Why does this happens?

What I were expecting:

`mypass mypass Passed`

Comment: You should be hashing user passwords, not encrypting them.

Comment: This code prints a variable named `_userPasswordInput` but compares `decrypted == _userPasswordinput` (note the difference in capitalization).  Do you actually have two different variables?  Is this your actual (copied-and-pasted) code?  Is that your actual (copied-and-pasted) output?

Comment: @RichardHeap Asking as a beginner, if its impossible to get the original value of hashed string then how is it possible to determine if the user entered password is the same as the hashed password? like is there any algorithm that can be use?

Comment: @jamesdlin It was a typo in the post not in my code.

Comment: How do we know that there aren't any other typos?  You must copy-paste code and output, not retype them.

Comment: @jamesdlin There isn't any typo in my actual code you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: And what about the output?  You're claiming that two `String`s that look the same don't compare equal.  Especially with this type of question, it's *critical* that you don't retype anything, because there's something subtle that you're overlooking, and if you don't copy-paste, we have no guarantee that you didn't overlook it when retyping it, despite any assurances you might make.  We don't know that you aren't typing what you *think* you see instead of what you *actually* see.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest that you try replacing `print(_userPasswordInput)` and `print(decrypted)` with `print(_userPasswordInput.codeUnits)` and `print(decrypted.codeUnits)` instead and compare the output.

Comment: Regarding the hashing thing: if you're storing credentials to log in to a service you don't control, and if that service doesn't provide some other authentication mechanism, then you'll probably have to store the user's password.  If you do control the service, then yes, you should store a (salted) hash.  You can verify if the password is correct by using the same hash algorithm (and same salt) on the user's input and comparing the hash result to the known hash.

Comment: Any time a user sets or resets their password, you securely generate a random salt, hash the password with the salt and store the salt and the hash. When you want to authenticate that user you retrieve the stored hash and salt, recalculate the hash using the salt and presented password and compare the hashes. If and only if the presented password matches the original password will the hashes match (within reasonable bounds of probability). Don't roll your own - use something like `bcrypt` or `scrypt` as the hash.